# Role based firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We need to verify the user's role inside the firebase rules. A user can have one of the following roles: SUPPORT, ADMIN, MODERATOR.

The User object contains a roles collection, so that we are able to put some meta data on the respective role:
[User Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UChlY.png)

I tried to use this collection inside my firestore rules but I did not yet succeeded:

```
    function getUserRoles(userId) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/roles);
    }

    function hasRole(userId, role) {
        return getUserRoles(userId) in role;
    }
```

Unfortunately I was not able to find something in the docs how I can check if the role list contains the requeted `role` as  document ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` is only able to fetch a single document, not an entire collection.  So, what you're trying right now is just not possible.  Also bear in mind that you can only `get()` up to 10 documents per request.

Consider rewriting `hasRole` like this in order to check if the user's roles collection contains a document with the named permission:

```
function hasRole(userId, role) {
    return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/roles/$(role))
}
```

This assumes `role` is the string name of the role, for example, "SUPPORT".  You will have to call this function for each individual role you want to check.

If you need to check the contents of the document as well, you will have to `get()` it instead, and look at the fields of the document..

Comment: Thank you so much! `return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/roles/$(role));` helped!